# NLTK extract categories present in text and map to a taxonomy

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, taxonomy

How can I map the categories extracted by my program from a text analysis (using NLP/NLTK or Textblob) to a standard (or almost standard) taxonomy

Preferably open source products

I would also prefer to download the selected taxonomies (by theme) and work offline over them in Python (than use an online service/api)

I've just found this on the subject...
[http://www.iab.com/guidelines/iab-quality-assurance-guidelines-qag-taxonomy/](http://IAB%20Taxonomies)

Comment: Try googling for WordNet, SUMO, OntoNotes, Freebase, YAGO2, Chebi, UMLS, depends on the domain, there's lots out there, just got to dig hard in googling ;P

Answer (score 2):

There are several companies which provide REST API for classifications. I tried those three below which where applicable for me.

1) AYLIEN - NLP service

2) https://www.uclassify.com/ - providing multiple NLP classifiers

3) https://iab.taxonome.org - I found this one very simple and easy to use, they also have a kind free trial and some video classifications demo